# Sql queries usng SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I have these table from a database. The table WORKER has 2 fields one of them is ID_W(number) and the other is DUTY(text).
WORKER(ID_W,DUTY)

I want to create an sql query that selects only ID_W(id of worker) which have the same DUTY where DUTY is a text type field.
Can someone help me? I want to use an aggregate function but none of them helps.

Comment: What do you mean by *where DUTY is a text type field*?

Comment: the table WORKER has 2 fields one of them is ID_W and the other is DUTY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a temp table for an example but this would do what you are wanting I believe:

```
SELECT Duty,
STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST(ID_W AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM #WORKER 
    WHERE Duty = T.DUTY
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS IDs FROM #WORKER T
GROUP BY Duty
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are looking for *only* the IDs of the workers whose `DUTY` field matches that of another worker.

You can do this with a `WHERE EXISTS` clause, but you need to `CONVERT` the `TEXT` column into a `VARCHAR (MAX)` in order to compare them.  This conversion on both sides will make the query expensive, but this is another way to do it:

```
Select  ID_W
From    WORKER  A
Where   Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    WORKER  B
    Where   A.ID_W <> B.ID_W
    And     Convert(Varchar (Max), A.DUTY) = Convert(Varchar (Max), B.DUTY)
)
```